# Zend_navigation: combine custom partial with selecting container

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-navigation

I'm rendering menu with custom partial but I need more than one menu so I want to select specific container for each view but `renderMenu($container)` overwrites `setPartial()`.

Is there any way of selecting container and render it content with my partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

renderMenu() shouldn't be using the setPartial() setting. In order to render the partial try to use renderPartial, here is the api:

```
//class Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu extends Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_HelperAbstract

public function renderPartial(Zend_Navigation_Container $container = null,
                                  $partial = null)
```

so you can specify the container and the partial when using this method without strictly needing to register a container or use setPArtial().